# What’s up with the Favicon?

Tags: discussion, bug

In the last couple/few days, I have noticed the favicon go from the Apple clover on a white background to a bold letter “A” on a red background.

Did we change anything or are we in the midst of a redesign?

The direct links work and it’s happening on both Firefox and Edge using my iPad.  Safari has the correct icon, but I use that sparingly.  The favicon is correct for Meta.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the page source, the following two icons are loaded

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/apple/Img/favicon.ico?v=30f8d738fc74">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/apple/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=daa7ff1d953e">
```

Do the direct links still work for you? What if you switch browsers, do you get the correct Favicon there?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I updated my question.  The direct links work and it affects both FF and Edge but not Safari (as of yet).

Comment: @allan Firefox works for me, on both iPhone and iPad. I assume you did the usual cache cleaning etc?

Comment: Yeah, first thing I did was cache clean and it seemed the icon appeared “quicker” if I can describe it that way.  I’ll check on my Mac when I get home today, but thus far it’s on FF and Edge but not Safari on my iPad.  Safari still has the correct favicon.  On a similar note, I have noticed over the past month that both FF and Edge will seem to loose my session cookies because if I leave for 30 mins, but open up again, SE/AD presents me with the “Accept all cookies” even though I never logged out or closed the tab.

Comment: @Allan For what it's worth, I've just tested using Firefox and Edge on both macOS and iOS and everything is loading fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @Monomeeth, I’ll keep investigating here.  This make no sense..